# How to play an instance of AVAudioBuffer?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiobuffer

On IOS, if you have an instance of AVAudioBuffer, how do you play it?

Note that I am NOT asking how to play an instance of AVAudioPCMBuffer.

There is a an Apple API that I'm using that returns/creates an AVAudioBuffer.

I have considered AVAudioEngine and AVAudioPlayerNode, but they only accept AVAudioPCMBuffer.

I have considered the higher level AVAudioPlayer, but it accepts "Data."

I find it very odd that the higher level API accepts the lowest level data format possible.  How is it even supposed to know what the audio format is if it's constructed with pure data?

Anyways, to re-iterate, how do you play an AVAudioBuffer?  If you can't then why do they exist?

Comment: Could [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/689461) help? Seems like AVAudioBuffer is an abstract type that you need to cast in order to do related logic. It would help if you share some code to understand what it is you are trying to accomplish and how you are getting the AVAudioBuffer.